# Why __proto__ reference name look like wrong for inherited object?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, properties, v8

```
class Human{
    talk(){
        return 'talking';
    }
}
class SuperHuman extends Human{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.age = 12;
    }
    fly(){
        return 'flying';
    }
}
let me = new Human();
let you = new SuperHuman();
you.gender = 'male';
console.log(you);
let she = Object.create(you);
console.log(she);
```

when study prototypal inheritance the she(object) **proto** looks like this.

[image: shows out put]

but my expectation is it should look like this...

[image: but my expected output]

Why it shows in this way?

Comment: Hi! Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Honestly I find this pretty confusing too. Not sure why the Chrome devtools chose to display `.__proto__.constructor.name` there.

Comment: @JonasWilms - It's showing (speaking loosely) the *type* or kind of the object `__proto__` refers to.

Comment: @t.j. yeah, but actually that's the next object in the hierarchy. I'd expect that anybody looking at that hierarchy is familiar with the prototype chain, this "type" is rather class like thinking. I think the devtools mix two concepts here in a confusing way.

Comment: @JonasWilms - Oh, I agree it's confusing -- certainly I've been confused by it more than once. :-) Also, they really shouldn't be using `__proto__` where they mean `[[Prototype]]`. :-)

Comment: Worth raising an issue to chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devtools is just telling you that the prototype of `she` is **a** `SuperHuman` (specifically, `you`), not that the prototype is the function `SuperHuman`.

The prototype chain of `she` is:

```
she −> you −> SuperHuman.prototype −> Human.prototype −> Object.prototype
```

- `she`'s prototype is `you` because you created it with `Object.create(you)`.
- `you`'s prototype is `SuperHuman.prototype` because you created it with `new SuperHuman`.
- `SuperHuman.prototype`'s prototype is `Human.prototype` because you created the `SuperHuman` function via `class SuperHuman extends Human` which sets up two chains of inheritance (one for the `prototype` objects and the other for the functions themselves).
- `Human.prototype`'s prototype is `Object.prototype` because that's what `class` does when there's no `extends`.

---

As a complete aside, it's unfortunate that some devtools implementations (such as the one in Chromium-based browsers) use `__proto__` where what they mean is [`[[Prototype]]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots). For one thing, it encourages using `__proto__`, which one shouldn't (not all objects have it and it can be shadowed; always use `Object.getPrototypeOf` or `Object.setPrototypeOf`). Separately, it's misleading: Chromium's devtools will happily show you `__proto__` for an object that doesn't have the `__proto__` accessor property at all  because it doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype` (which is where the accessor comes from):

```js
// An object with no prototype
const p = Object.create(null);

// An object using that as its prototype
const c = Object.create(p);

// An object inheriting from Object.prototype has the `__proto__` accessor property:
console.log("__proto__" in {}); // true

// `c` does not have the `__proto__` accessor property:
console.log("__proto__" in c); // false

// And yet, Chromium's devtools show you one if you expand it in the console
console.log(c);
```

```html
Look in the real browser console.
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I go into the inheritance chains set up by `class` syntax in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 4 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: "*it's unfortunate that some devtools implementations use `__proto__` where what they mean is `[[Prototype]]`.*" - couldn't agree more. They use bracket syntax for other internals already, so why not here? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=817305